# how to attach multiple files to email in opencart

Tags: php, email, opencart

I am working on opencart module. I want to send multiple files from my download directory and send them as attachment via email. Currently i have done some code, It doesn't send single email with multiple attachments, it sends multiple emails or sends one email with last file name. here is the code.

```
$oresumeCtr = 0;
$filePaths = array();
if (isset($this->request->post['selected']) && $this->validate_resume_eMail()) {
        foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $applicant_id) {
        $resume_name = $this->model_catalog_career->getapplicantresume($applicant_id);
        $upload_resume = $resume_name[0]['upload_resume'];
        $filePaths[$oresumeCtr] = DIR_DOWNLOAD ."/resumes/" . $upload_resume;   
        $this->log->write('resume path name' .$filePaths);
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
        $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
        $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
        $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
        $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
        $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');            

        $mail->setTo($this->request->get['emailid']);
        $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setSender('ifixandrepair.com');
        $mail->setSubject("Resume");
        $message = '<p>Please find attached Resume. <br />Thanks. </p><p>';
        $mail->setHtml($message);
        foreach($filePaths as $filePath) {
            if (isset($filePath) && file_exists($filePath)) {
                $mail->addAttachment($filePath);
           $this->log->write('resume path in side loop  ' .$filePath);
            }

            }
        }
                   $mail->send();

        echo "<center>Resume sent to the email address <b>" . $this->request->get['emailid'] ."</b> successfully.</center>";
}
```

Comment: You might get some more responses if you edit that example code for proper indentation, specifically for the nested loops.  It's hard to tell where the loops end given that indentation.  Unrelated:  can you post some example log output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attaching multiple files to addattachment() php opencart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287265/attaching-multiple-files-to-addattachment-php-opencart)