# Attaching multiple files to addattachment() php opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to send multiple attachments in a single email. I get file paths from my download directory and store them in an array and than using for each loop  attach them to mail->addattachment($filepath), but it always selects the last attachment.I havent added my foreach code for getting file names from DB.

**For logs if i do print_r($filePaths); it gives me this output**

```
Array ( [0] => /home/ifixandm/public_html/finalUpGrade/download/resumes/03-02-2016_amir_ETicket-EmmiratsView.pdf ) 
Array ( [0] => /home/ifixandm/public_html/finalUpGrade/download/resumes/04-02-2016_Florida-Mall_Ammar-ul-hassan.pdf )
```

**Here is my code.**

```
$oresumeCtr = 0;
$filePaths = array();
$filePaths[$oresumeCtr] = DIR_DOWNLOAD ."/resumes/" . $upload_resume; // upload resume is name of resume 
foreach($filePaths as $filePath) {

   if (isset($filePath) && file_exists($filePath)) 
    {
    $mail->addAttachment($filePath);
    $this->log->write('resume path in side loop  ' .$filePath);
    }
}
$mail->send();
```

I want to send these files as attachments in a single email.

Comment: `download//resumes` shouldn't that be `download/resumes`

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan yes my bad removed that slas but still..

Comment: You need to increment the `$oresumeCtr` as the counter remains the same the array value is being over-ridden

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan after for each loop?

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan perfect it worked :)

Comment: You can see from the ouput of filePaths that they have the same index [0] is best to use glob to read your files.

Comment: @ArrowHead thanks it was a silly mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, I am assuming all you files are in pdf format.

```
foreach (glob(DIR_DOWNLOAD ."/resumes/*.pdf") as $filePath) {
    // do something with $filePath

    if (isset($filePath) && file_exists($filePath))
    {
        $mail->addAttachment($filePath);
        $this->log->write('resume path in side loop  ' .$filePath);
    }

}
```